# Why does this provided regular expression return true?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to know why following regular expression returns true:

```
reg = re.compile (r'[0-9]%')
reg.search ("50%")
```

`[0-9]` would match any single digit, in this case 5. But then 0 doesn't match %, so it should return false, but it returns true.

My code might have syntax errors, but you get the gist of it.

Comment: if you don't want your regular expression to *match* e.g. "5%" (but still match e.g. "15%"), you should really use `match` instead of `search`

Answer (score 8):

reg.search() matches the pattern anywhere in the string (so it matches the 0%).  If you want the entire string to match, try this:

re.compile(r'^[0-9]%$')

^ - matches the start of the string

$ - matches the end of the string

Answer (score 5):

This regex would match on the `0%` portion of `50%`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for single-digit percentages inside a longer string, you could use a [negative lookbehind](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re):

```
In [171]: print(re.search('(?<!\d)\d%',"Foo is 5% complete"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xab302f8>

In [172]: print(re.search('(?<!\d)\d%',"Foo is 50% complete"))
None

In [173]: print(re.search('(?<!\d)\d%',"5% complete"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xab301a8>

In [174]: print(re.search('(?<!\d)\d%',"50% complete"))
None
```

Answer (score 1):

As gfdunn2 mentioned, it does a 'rolling-match' of the entire string.  There are a couple things you can do to control it a bit better though.

The braces {} below can control how many characters you get, so it will give you much tighter matching.

```
>>> import re  

#exactly 1 digit and %
>>> test = re.compile(r'[0-9]{1}%')  
>>> print test.search("50%").group(0)  
0%  


#exactly 2 digits and %
>>> test = re.compile(r'[0-9]{2}%')  
>>> print test.search("50%").group(0)  
50%  


#one or more digits  
>>> test = re.compile(r'[0-9]+%')  
>>> print test.search("50%").group(0)  
50%  

#in the event you want to include floating point percentages  
>>> test = re.compile(r'[0-9.]+%')  
>>> print test.search("50.4%").group(0)  
50.4%

>>> print test.search("50.34%").group(0)
50.34%
```